# Tag synonyms on WordPress?

Tags: wordpress.com

Does WordPress have the concept of **tag synonyms** (like on Stack Exchange)? I would like to be able to link two tags (e.g., `math` and `mathematics`) on WordPress in ways similar to what we can do on Stack Exchange.

Comment: I am starting a plugin to make marking synonyms possible. If you have feedback on how you would like it to work, I am looking for ideas at http://github.com/lgedeon/term-synonyms

Answer (score 1):

No, not really.

That's not to say that there isn't a plugin which might do what you want. (Only applies to self-hosted WordPress sites, though.)

Comment: Hmm, I tried merging tags, but usually I end up with an error message informing me that such a tag already exists... Is there something specific that I need to do to merge tags?

Comment: It's possible I'm misremembering and that I had a plugin that would allow me to merge tags in a self-hosted WordPress installation. I'll remove that bit until I can confirm it.